# How to move window buttons to the gnome shell 3.16 panel

Tags: gnome-shell

For older versions of gnome shell, there were extensions to move the window buttons (like close, maximize and minimize) from the window's title bar to the top panel.

- [Window Buttons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/426/window-buttons/)
- [Buttons to Panel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/buttons-to-panel/)

This is especially useful with windows without title bars, like [Maximus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/) causes fullscreen applications to be.

Both do not work on gnome shell version 3.16 and seen out of active development. Is there any similar extension currently maintained?

Answer (score 0):

You have no-title-bar-forked which works well!
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2015/no-title-bar-forked/